# 0..* Child Elements in Any Order With an "Any" Child Element

Tags: xsd

I'm trying to have any of these child elements in any order.  But I also want to allow for any additional elements as well.  When I add a new element that is not defined in teh choice list, I get a validation error "Element  is not allowed under element ."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" elementFormDefault="qualified" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
                This version of the Atom schema is based on version 1.0 of the format specifications,
                found here http://www.atomenabled.org/developers/syndication/atom-format-spec.php.
            </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/03/xml.xsd" />
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            An Atom document may have two root elements, feed and entry, as defined in section 2.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:element name="feed" type="atom:feedType"/>
    <xsd:element name="entry" type="atom:entryType"/>
```

...

```
<xsd:complexType name="feedType">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                The Atom feed construct is defined in section 4.1.1 of the format spec.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:choice minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="author" type="atom:personType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xsd:element name="category" type="atom:categoryType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xsd:element name="contributor" type="atom:personType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xsd:element name="generator" type="atom:generatorType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="icon" type="atom:iconType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="id" type="atom:idType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="link" type="atom:linkType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xsd:element name="logo" type="atom:logoType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="rights" type="atom:textType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="subtitle" type="atom:textType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="title" type="atom:textType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="updated" type="atom:dateTimeType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="entry" type="atom:entryType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xsd:any namespace="##other" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:choice>
        <xsd:attributeGroup ref="atom:commonAttributes"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<xsd:any>` by default doesn't allow you put any old guff in the document. It still requires the parser to have a schema for that element, and it must validate against that schema.

If you want to disable validation of that element, then use `processContents="skip"`, i.e.

```
<xsd:any namespace="##other" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" processContents="skip"/>
```

There's a good description of `processContents` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256043.aspx), and it's a good deal clearer than the impenetrable XML Schema spec.